# Conversion of timestamp to fractional epoch in AWS athena

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

We have one client table in athena where ts column is in ***timestamp*** datatype.

```
ts : 2022-10-05 06:15:00.090
```

If I want to select the record however the ts should be displayed as fractional epoch. For same result, in postgres we use

```
select id, extract(epoch from ts) as ts_sec from table_name
```

which returns `1, 1664950500.09`

I tried using date_diff function in Athena however it returns bigInt. I also tried using to_unixtime function however it returns `1.66495050009E9`

Is there a method/function in Athen which will return the value in fraction `1664950500.09`

My use case is that I have to use it in a group by clause. The query that I am currently executing in postgres is

```
select count(*) over () as data_count, extract(epoch from ts) as ts_sec from device_data where
         ts >= '2022-09-30 18:30:00.000000' and ts <= '2022-10-31 18:30:00.000000'
         and device_id = 760 and id in (1,2,3,4,5)
         group by ts_sec order by ts_sec desc limit 1
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `1.66495050009E9` equals `1664950500.09` except for the _presentation_. Yet `1.66495050009E9` == `1664950500.09` _is_ true.

Answer (score 0):

`1.66495050009E9` is just a presentation detail, if you need to format it in another way you can try using [`format`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#format) (not sure if it available in Athena, works in Trino which is the base for Athena v3 engine):

```sql
select format('%.2f', to_unixtime(timestamp '2022-10-05 06:15:00.090'));
```

Another approach you can try - casting to a decimal with precision.

```sql
select cast(to_unixtime(timestamp '2022-10-05 06:15:00.090') as decimal(18, 2));
```

Output:

```
     _col0
---------------
 1664950500.09
```